# Connect dvi monitor to docking with dvi and display port

Tags: display, dvi, cable, displayport, docking

I have a laptop with HDMI and mini DisplayPort. it connects to a docking station that has DVIs and DisplayPorts. I want to connect a monitor with  DVI port. What would be the best option in terms of display quality? note that I don't care about moving the audio to the monitor. I guess I can connect the monitor to the docking station with DVI to DVI, but would a cable of DVI in one side (connected to the monitor) converted to a DisplayPort on the other side (connected to the docking station) would give me some advantage in the resolution, refresh rate or any other display property?

Answer (score 0):

If your monitor accepts only DVI signal, it won't be capable of taking anything better than DVI. Even if the other end could theoretically support better quality image, it has to be converted to DVI eventually.